# Fabric run command - start sh script on the remote & leaving the remote script running

Tags: python, linux, ssh, fabric

Leaving the remote script running. is this possible?
I want to move on to other parts of the local script which
initiated the remote one, the console screen keeps
getting interrupted with output from the remote.

I am running a `script.sh` file, the script execute an application.
I am trying to break the connection after running the script and continue with my fabfile. Today the run command hangs out.

The syntax that works in bash for me:

```
ssh user@server  ".... script.sh &> /dev/null &" &
```

How can I do it in my fabfile?

Comment: Check what fabric documentation says about this question: http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html?highlight=background#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang

Comment: Thanks on the tip. not sure it will help.

Comment: This is my solution after some attempts:  run('(( export Display=1.0 && myscript.sh 2>/dev/null &/dev/null &) ' ,pty=False).  thanks for the help.